# Maven Assembly: can I include files inside an attached zip in another dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Suppose I have two Maven projects:

- core_cli, which uses the assembly plug-in to generate core_cli.zip, this contains alldeps.jar (i.e., all the Java dependencies), plus a couple of files, such as run.sh, config/config.properties (at the zip's root level). The zip is attached and deployed into Maven repositories, when I issue the deploy command.
- extd_cli, which is an extension of core_cli, it has a new alldeps.jar (which inherits the dependencies of core_cli and has a few more classes), but the other files in the zip are the same.

Is that possible in Maven? I've experimented with http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-controlling-contents.html, but no luck, any depdendencySet block seems to always refer to the dependency .jar, never the attached .zip.

Comment: You need to use the assembly id of core_cli assembly descriptor in the dependency (extd_cli) as classifier done so?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. I don't need to reuse assembly descriptors, just to re-use certain files in the core and place them in the distribution binary for ext.

Comment: So please show what you actually have in a example project.

Comment: I need to create an extension of this: https://github.com/EBIBioSamples/myequivalents/tree/master/myequivalents-cmdline. The new module will have this myequivalents-cmdline as dependency and will create a .zip with more commands. Such zip will contain the new project dependencies (doing this is not a problem), plus all the extra-files that are already included in the current .zip, ie, anything in src/main/assembly/resources.

Comment: This is currently done by deps.xml and pkg.xml. The problem is that those extra files don't go in the jar that Maven creates by default and this seems the only one that Assembly sees, when I use depdendencySet in the new dependant module (ie, it doesn't see the .zip created by the dependency, despite it being deployed in the Maven repo). I'm almost resigned to add such files to the main jar too.